# SQL Count of stock in storage for business assets

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I'm working to design an asset management system for a business I work with. They employee people in a work from home environment.

I have a database design started, but I'm not certain how to get the numbers for current stock on hand. For example, I know that the total count of my assets where description = "Mouse" is (3), but 1 was sent to John Doe and 1 was initially sent to Jane Doe, but it was returned as it was broken. So I have 1 mouse left to send to Jane.

**What would be the SQL query to use so I get the total amount of "Mouse" assets currently sitting in storage?**

I see it as

> [total stock(Mouse) minus shipments out with (Mouse)] + [count of return shipments with (Mouse) where returned = "1" minus count of stock(Mouse) where decommissioned = "1"]

Here's where I'm at:

```
Tables:

Employees
ID (Primary key, incremental)
F_Name
L_Name
Address
Phone_Number

+----+---------+----------+-----------------+--------------------------
| ID |  F_Name |  L_Name  | Address         |  Phone_Number
| 122  John      Smith      123 anywhere...    111-222-3333
| 123  John      Doe        128 somewhere...   222-333-4444
| 135  Jane      Doe        128 somewhere...   222-333-4444

Shipments_Outbound
ID (Primary key, incremental)
Employee_ID (Foreign key, references Employees(ID))
Sent (date value for date left warehouse)
Courier_ID

+----+--------------+------------+---------------------------------
| ID |  Employee_ID |  Sent      | Courier_ID
| 001   123           2016-03-12   2223334445
| 002   135           2017-03-12   3334445556


Contents_Outbound (many to many composite from Shipments_Outbound and Assets)
Shipment_ID (Primary key, references Shipments_Outbound(ID))
Asset_ID (Primary key, references Assets(ID)

+------------+-----------
| Shipment_ID|  Asset_ID 
| 001            001
| 001            004
| 001            005
| 002            002
| 002            003
| 002            006

Assets
ID (Primary key, incremental)
SKU (unique)
Description
Decommissioned (tinyint value for discarded equipment)
Comments (to note why discarded)

+----+---------+---------------+-----------------+-------------
| ID |  SKU    |  Description  | Decommissioned  | Comments
|001   123456    Monitor          0
|002   987654    Monitor          0          
|003   456789    Desktop          0
|004   NULL      Mouse            0
|005   NULL      Keyboard         0
|006   NULL      Mouse            1                 Broken scroll wheel
|007   NULL      Mouse            0

Shipments_Return
ID (Primary key, incremental)
Employee_ID (Foreign key, references (Employees(ID))
Issued (Date value for when return waybill issued for employee)
Courier_ID
Returned (tinyint for boolean on if product was returned)

+----+---------+---------------+-----------------+-------------
| ID |  Employee_Id |  Issued  | Courier_ID  | Returned
|222     123          2018-01-12  9998887776    0
|223     135          2018-01-13  8887776665    1

Contents_Return (many to many composite from Shipments_Return and Assets)
ShipmentR_ID (Primary key, references Shipments_Return(ID))
Asset_ID (Primary key, references Assets(ID)

+-------------+-----------
| ShipmentR_ID|  Asset_ID 
| 222            001
| 222            004
| 223            002
| 223            006
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do your query that way. You might run into issues, however, with other scenarios.

You have one widget. Your Query would say Instock says Total 1 - shipments (0) + returns (0) - decommissioned (0) = 1. Fine

You ship it to to a worker. Instock says Total 1 - shipped 1 + returns 0 - decommissioned 0 = 0.  Fine

What happens if the worker's house is robbed and the widget disappears? Or they have a fire. Or the widget never arrives to the worker in the first place. If you just decommission it, you will get Total 1 - shipped 1 + returns 0 - decommissioned 1 = -1. If you don't decommission it, then as far as you know it is always at the worker's place, which is not correct. You won't have a return, they can't return it. You would have to make up a fake return just to get your numbers right.

You need to have a query that ignores the decommissioned assets at every step, something like

```
total stock(Mouse) where decommissioned = 0
minus shipments out with (Mouse) where decommissioned = 0
plus return shipments with (Mouse) where returned = "1" and decommissioned = 0
```

Alternatively, you could add a status column on Asset, linking to a status table with values like "In Stock", "In Use", "Decommissioned". On creation, an asset would be set to "In Stock". When a shipment is done, all assets in the shipment would be changed to "In Use". On a return (when returned set to 1) all assets in the return would be changed to "In Stock". When decommissioned, set status to decommissioned, etc. You could add other status values like "Repairing", "Being Returned" for other situations if you decided you need them.

Then you query above would be something like

```
Total(Mouse) where Status = <in-stock status>
```

Comment: Simply brilliant. Thank you very much, this helps tremendously!